# how upload image to folder and display it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to upload image to folder (using FileUpload) by pressing one submit button to whole form. i manage to upload the image to separate folders but i can't display it.
thank you.

```
    String fname;
    FileUpload tempFU = new FileUpload();
    string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\images\\" + ulProj.groupCode;
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    try
    {
        tempFU = (FileUpload)customerUC.FindControl("CustomerLogoUrlFU");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        fname = path + "\\" + tempFU.FileName;
        tempFU.SaveAs(fname);
        tempCus.logoUrl = fname;
    }
    catch
    {
        //return;
    }
```

Comment: You should just give the (valid)path of the image to a src attribute of an image tag. What is your problem?

Comment: I strongly suggest you get rid of that try/catch block.

Comment: i did, but it still doesn't display it

Comment: @user3025441: is `tempCus` an Image control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Points to remember:**

1. you should use `tilde` `~` operator to represent the current project
       `root folder`.
2. use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to combine your `path` and `filename` to get the valid complete path.
3. you are creating the `Directory` for the given `path` 2 times. so remove the later part where you are creating the `Directory` 2'nd time.
4. as said in the above `comments` as your `catch` block is not having anycode,
   remove the `try-catch` block

**Complete Solution:**

```
    String fname;
    FileUpload tempFU = new FileUpload();
    string path = Server.MapPath(@"~\images\" + ulProj.groupCode);
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    tempFU = (FileUpload)customerUC.FindControl("CustomerLogoUrlFU");        
    fname = System.IO.Path.Combine(path,tempFU.FileName);
    tempFU.SaveAs(fname);
    tempCus.logoUrl = fname;
```